# Subtract one from the sum of the first item in a nested list in r

Tags: r

I have an initial nested list (list of lists) of vectors of integers with `NA` values randomly replacing some integers. Within a nested list, if one vector contains all `NA` values, it needs to be broken up into two lists (or more, if more than one vector in the nested list contains all `NA`s). I ultimately need a vector of values that sums the length nested lists minus 1, i.e. `sum(lengths(list[[i]]-1`, where `i` is the list of vectors in the nested list, and removes any values less than or equal to 0.

So far I have been able to do this, but realized that if a list is 'artificially' broken into 2+ lists, I only need to subtract one from the first position of the nested list. Furthermore, if the first position of the nested list is `NA`, the subsequent lists in the nested list do not need to be subtracted by 1.

Below is some sample code that provides examples of the full nested list, the nested list with NA values randomly assigned, and the final desired vector of sums for the example lists.

```
#Full List
L.full<-list(list(1,3,c(0,2,0),c(0,0)),list(1,6,c(0,3,2,0,1,0),c(0,0,0,1,0,0),1,2,c(0,1),2,c(0,0)),
             list(1,0),list(1,0),list(1,4,c(2,0,0,0),c(4,1),c(1,0,0,0,0),0),list(1,0))
#Nested list with "random" NAs
L.miss<-list(list(1,3,c(0,NA,0),c(0,0)),list(1,6,c(0,3,NA,0,NA,0),c(0,NA,0,1,0,0),1,NA,c(0,1),2,c(0,0)),
             list(1,NA),list(1,0),list(1,NA,c(NA,0,0,0),c(NA,NA),c(1,0,0,NA,0),0),list(1,0))
#Desired final output
L.want<-c(5,11,5,1,3,5,1)
```

The below code may be a bit inelegant but *almost* gets me where I need to be; it outputs the final vector as `[5,11,4,1,2,4,1]`, not the desired `[5,11,5,1,3,5,1]`. How can I have the code subtract one from just the first element in the list, if it is present?

```
#Break apart 
test<-lapply(lapply(seq_along(L.miss), function(nm) {split(L.miss[[nm]], cumsum(sapply(L.miss[[nm]], function(x) all(is.na(x)))))}), function(lstA) lapply(lstA,function(x) Filter(function(y) !all(is.na(y)), x)))
#Bring the nested list up a level
test2<-unlist(test,recursive=FALSE)
#Remove NA values
test3<-rapply(test2,function(x) x[!is.na(x)], how="replace") #remove NAs
#Sum nested lists
test4<-integer()
for (i in 1:length(test3)){
  test4[i]<-sum(lengths(test3[[i]]))-1
} 
test5<-test4[test4>0] #remove values <=0
```

Thank you - if this question is too specific for this forum, please let me know and I will remove it.

Comment: More specific is better, and thanks for providing data and the expected outcome.

Comment: I am not clear how you get `L.want`. For example, can you explain how you get `L.want[5]` i.e 3 with `L.full[[5]]` and `L.miss[[5]]` ?

Comment: Happy to clarify - the 5th position in `L.full` is a list of six vectors. `L.miss` randomly replaces the integers with `NA`. Since position `2` and position `4` in `L.miss[[5]]` have all integers replaced with `NA`s, it should be 'broken' into three "lists": `[1]`, `[NA,0,0,0]`, and a list of two last two vectors, `[1,0,0,NA,0]` and `[0]`. Since I am then removing the NA values, subtracting one from the first position, summing the length of all the lists in the nested list, and removing all lists with 0 values, `L.miss[[5]]` should ultimately contribute as the `3` and `5` in `L.want'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I solved it - it was much simpler to delete the first position in the initial `L.miss` nested list  then ignore the whole "minus 1" altogether:

```
#Delete first instance
l<-L.miss
for (i in 1:length(l)){
  l[[i]][[1]]<-NULL
}

#Same code as above but for loop sums without -1
test<-lapply(lapply(seq_along(l), function(nm) {split(l[[nm]], cumsum(sapply(l[[nm]], function(x) all(is.na(x)))))}), function(lstA) lapply(lstA,function(x) Filter(function(y) !all(is.na(y)), x)))
test2<-unlist(test,recursive=FALSE)
test3<-rapply(test2,function(x) x[!is.na(x)], how="replace") #remove NAs
test4<-integer()
for (i in 1:length(test3)){
  test4[i]<-sum(lengths(test3[[i]]))
} 
test5<-test4[test4>0] #remove values <=0

#result
#> test5
#[1]  5 11  5  1  3  5  1
```